# How to renew automatic the automation account certificate?

Tags: azure, azure-runbook

I would like to renew the certificate of the automation account automatically because I have multiple clients and I would like to automate the renew.

I would like to create a runbook and scheduled once a year to renew the certificate automatically

Answer (score 0):

A comment in [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/34512) GitHub issue has all the details that are required to automatically renew the certification.